# PostgreSQL 9.6 error: invalid resource manager ID

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am encountering error messages like this in a PostgreSQL 9.6 server log file (while experimenting with `pg_rewind`):

```
LOG: invalid resource manager ID 119 at 0/910CE68
```

What is a (PostgreSQL) resource manager and why does it have to by identified in a WAL file?

Comment: what is your O.S environment?

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan It's Debian 8.9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have by now concluded that this is a symptom of PostgreSQL encountering malformed WALs. These error messages also seem related:

```
LOG: invalid record length ...
LOG: record with incorrect prev-link ...
```

The root cause was apparently that a call to `pg_basebackup -X stream` did not terminate. (This was apparently an issue titled `"pg_basebackup -x stream from the standby gets stuck if there is no traffic in the database"` that was [resolved in PostgreSQL 9.2](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_9.2_Open_Items#Resolved_Issues), but may have [cropped up again](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pgsql.hackers/M_Px87HAwJw/NhRHgqcDvbMJ).) When I had to interrupt the call with `CTRL-C`, this may have left malformed WALs.

I am now using `pg_basebackup -c fast -X fetch` instead, and this works fine. Given that and for my current purposes, it is no longer necessary to understand details around (PostgreSQL) resource managers.